# One attribute is a Foreign Key. can a foreign key refer to three different tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am thinking of a database design.
I have one table whose column is a foreign key. I want that foreign key can be referenced to column of three different table.
Is it possible? How will I write create table query for this?
Example
three table: Movie, Book, TV.. each has one column known as URL.
Another table People has column URL which can refer to URL of any one of the three tables
Is this something possible?

Answer (score 1):

If you need something like this, it should be a sign that your design has issues.

The best method to handle something of this nature is to make a `URL` table, and point ALL your `URL` references to that table.

Comment: This seems plausible, Each of the three table has url as primary key. Adding another new table which will be used when creating or deleting . WOnt it be bad design as it its taking extra space and used only for deletion and creation

Comment: The URL is the primary key?  That seems like a really bad choice for a PK, since web addresses can change so easily...

Comment: oki I'll think abt primary key something else but anyways could you comment on my previous comment on extra space ??

Comment: PK will be considered as a fK in other

Answer (score 0):

You can use two columns for this purpose: one column that contains the id of the row in the other table and one column that contains the type of the item (e.g., movie, book, television).

To answer your question, yes it's possible but just the number won't be enough because there can be multiple rows in different tables with the same id.